# Query mysql get max and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

please help,
i want get max "urutan" and group by "ntstk"

result like picture with highlight
[image]

Comment: What have you tried besides pressing print screen and CTRL + V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correlated subquery

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where t1.urutan=( select max(urutan) from table_name t2 where t1.ntstk=t2.ntstk)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like that

```
SELECT ntstk, max(urutan) FROM table GROUP BY ntstk
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get these list of columns, you can join the `max() urutan` using a `subquery`.

```
 select t1.* from
    tableA t1
    inner join
      (select max(urutan) max_urutan, ntstk from tableA group by ntstk) t2
        on t2.ntstk = t1.ntstk  and t2.max_urutan = t1.urutan
```